# How to write cross-product of two vectors in latex?

Tags: symbols

I have been looking for the cross product symbol in latex, but haven't found any yet.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try $\vec{a} \times \vec{b}$.

Comment: Thanks! It worked.

Answer (score 3):

`\times` is the command commonly used for the cross product.

In general, I suggest trying [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) for such matters.

Comment: Some authors use `\wedge` to denote the cross product, although that creates confusion with the actual wedge product. In three dimensions they are the same though.

Answer (score 1):

The `mandi` package explains all and can be found at -- http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mandi/mandi.pdf

[image]

[image]

Comment: I maintain the `mandi` package and it's currently undergoing revision. Please feel free to give me feedback.